# FastCGI for C++

Tags: c++, fastcgi

I've found only two FastCGI libraries for C++. There's the ["official" one](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/21), and [fastcgi++](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/fastcgipp/). How is either one better than the other? Do any others exist?

Comment: Could be some good leads here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746309/which-is-the-best-c-web-framework

Comment: @AssafLavie, Now how is that related.

Comment: I've recently found [Cutelyst](https://github.com/cutelyst/cutelyst) for C++/Qt which supports FastCGI. Rather easier than writing from scratch on top of raw FastCGI library :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As fastcgi++ is still listed as "Development Status: 4- Beta" so I would suggest going for the official one. It has been around for ages and has bindings for a whole host of languages. Licences between the 2 don't seem to make much difference. Put some measurements in your code and if performance is an issue then spend some time playing around with alternatives.

Comment: fastcgi++ is in "Development Status: 5 - Production/Stable" since April 5, 2018. The official FastCGI is now unsupported and the website went away.

Answer (score 9):

What you probably want is hidden in the `contrib` directory of Cgicc package.

`fcgi-test.cpp` is an example of how to use cgicc with FastCGI.

Path to the installed `fcgi-test.cpp` should be
`/usr/share/doc/libcgicc-doc/examples/contrib/fcgi-test.cpp`

Answer (score 6):

The official library is rather low-level, and as such, is only useful as an intermediate for a high-level CGI library such as cgicc.

Fastcgi++, on the other hand, allows for use of C++ idioms when dealing with FastCGI. Incompleteness in v1 motivated me to fork it into mosh-fcgi.

Pros:
My fork complies with every point of the standard (especially ROLE_FILTER)
everything's extensively templated, so it's easier to use arbitrary T for std::basic_strings.
Cons:
My modifications are in alpha mode.

In any case, download the latest zip from https://github.com/moshbear/mosh-fcgi.

Answer (score 5):

See also the Cgicc library:

http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/

The library appears to be mature (currently at version 3.x). According to the documentation it can be used with FastCGI by passing a custom reader (reader_function_t) to the constructor of the Cgicc class.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pretty library for creating FastCGI daemons: https://github.com/golubtsov/Fastcgi-Daemon

Answer (score 2):

The C-version of FastCGI does very little, and developing in C++ isn't such a big problem as it hardly interferes with your own code. It's most likely just a loop and an environment variable.

So my advice would be just to stick with the official version.

Just be aware of one thing: it works by redefining `printf`! So if you use `cout` it won't work.