# reg fcgi and c++

Tags: c++, fastcgi, mod-fcgid, lighttpd

I am developing a sample using c++ which will get request from lighttpd webserver using fcgi protocol and process the request and send the response to client.

I could not find any samples using fcgi + lighttpd + c++ application.

I am struggling for a week.

Please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that you mean [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI), not FCGI (but Googling on *FCGI* gives you *FastCGI* immediately, so you should know that).

Googling for *Fastcgi C++* gives immediately a lot of examples and good libraries. I'm very surprised you are struggling for an entire week. In particular:

1. [fastcgipp](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/) is a C++ library for FastCGI, and it has several examples inside.
2. [wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) is a C++ library to write self-contained C++ web servers and has a good FastCGI mode. There are many examples inside.
3. [CGI on SourceForge](http://cgi.sourceforge.net/) is also a FastCgi capable library
4. This [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774647/fastcgi-for-c) on StackOverflow is relevant
5. [fastcgi-app](http://code.google.com/p/fastcgi-app/) is also interesting.
6. etc...

**You really should better use search engines**. If you are really struggling for a whole week on something that simple, you'll have trouble making any FastCGI applications. It is very surprising that by a single Google search I found dozens of relevant answers in a minute, and that you had to work an entire week without success.